# Can't find custom field name in IBM RTC

Tags: xml, rational-team-concert

I have a custom RTC work item with the field 'Business Unit (BU)'

[image]

I need to find the API xml element name for this item, in the past I've been able to find them no problem by going to a url formatted like this to see the xml data:

https://company.com:1111/ccm/oslc/workitems/252829

Where 252829 is the id of the work item, but if I control + f search on this page for Business Unit or business or even the value 'AMI', there are no results, all the other fields show up fine except for the one i need, Business Unit (BU).

Does it have something to do with the lightbulb button next to the rtc value? Do I need a different url in order to view tall the rtc xml values? I was hoping it would be something like `rtc_cm:BusinessUnit`

Answer (score 0):

The icon (lightbulb + list) should have a label.
For instance, as in [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/144950/rtc-filed-against-guess-category), "guess category".

> "The Guess Category button attempts to guess the correct category by using the text in the Summary and Description fields to search for similar work items."
>
> As I understand it, it doesn't look for a similarity between the text and the category name ... it does a search for the work item whose summary/description is a best match for the text, and then suggests the category of the work item.
> Try typing in words that match the summary/description of some existing work item.

In other words, if this is a dynamic field based on a runtime search, you would not see any static value when you go to URL you mention.